# Renaming files using alternate BaseName lookup (CSV) names

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have an exported CSV file with the below table

```
"Directory","BaseName"
"E:\Movie Files\Movie (2000)","Movie"
"E:\Movie Files\Movie (2001)","Movie 2"
```

My code is very close to what I want and that is basically rename the `cover.jpg` in each folder to the basename of the movie and add `-poster.jpg` after it, e.g. `Movie-poster.jpg`, `Movie 2-poster.jpg`.

It works for the first folder but every folder after this uses the same basename from the first folder. It doesn't recurse for every folder within the root location like I thought it would. So for Movie (2001) I end up having `Movie-poster.jpg`, not `Movie 2-poster.jpg`.

This is the code that's not quite there:

```
$lines = Import-Csv 'E:\Output.csv'
foreach ($line in $lines) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path .\* -File -Filter '*Cover*' -Recurse |
        Rename-Item -NewName ($line.BaseName + '-poster.jpg')
}
```

Expected results as mentioned above is that each `cover.jpg` in each folder and sub-folders will be renamed to match the basename according to their locations.

Comment: EDIT Changed where it mentioned folder.jpg to cover.jpg. Cover.jpg was my code testing file name, code was correct with the test filter 'cover'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You end up with all covers being renamed to `Movie-poster.jpg` because your code renames all covers under the current working directory (`.`) in the first iteration of your loop, so there are no files with the string "Cover" in their name left when the loop goes into the second iteration.

Process the directories from your CSV instead of processing the current working directory for each of them, and use the current object from the pipeline (`$_`) for renaming the files. For the latter you also must replace the parentheses with curly brackets.

Change this:

```
foreach ($line in $lines) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path .\* -File -Filter '*Cover*' -Recurse |
        Rename-Item -NewName ($line.BaseName + '-poster.jpg')
}
```

into this:

```
foreach ($line in $lines) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $line.Directory -File -Filter '*Cover*' -Recurse |
        Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName + '-poster.jpg'}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ansgar for the comment. It didn't work in my instance, what it did was rename ALL the files (including those that already had the correct naming convention) to be cover-poster.jpg however the code did point me in the right direction with regards to $line.Directory.

The code that worked for me in the end was this;

```
# Renames Cover.jpg to match BaseName file with basename-poster.jpg
$lines = Import-Csv 'E:\Output.csv'
    ForEach ($line in $lines) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $line.Directory -file -filter '*Cover*' -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$line.BaseName + '-poster.jpg'}
}
```